# Using an if statment with a partial address to adress a link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, if-statement

Trying to figure out a way to use Javascript to set up a little if-else statement using only part of the url to determine if a link should go one place or another. So far what I got is,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1) 
{
        <a href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>
    } else {
        <a href="placetwo.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>
        }
 </script>
```

The problem is that the link doesn't even appear so I don't know how wrong or not I am.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Lets just say for the sake of argument it is a blank html page. As in `<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Looking for more of a proof of concept then branch out into getting this working on a full scale site.

Edit #2:
Figured it out, even has url detection.

```
<a id="link">link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var referrerUrl = document.referrer;
if (referrerUrl.indexOf("searchurlfor") != -1)
{
    link.href = "place1";
} else {
    link.href = "place2";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById)

HTML:

```
<a id="link">link</a>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.getElementById('link');
if (url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1) 
{
        link.href="placeone.com";
} else {
        link.href="placetwo.com";
}
 </script>
```

Comment: I'm just getting plain text back, not a link.

Comment: getELementById, should be getElementById. I capitalized the L on accessed. I've updated my code.

Comment: Still only getting text, no link.

Comment: The example worked great but lacks the part of seeing what site it is currently on without me typing in the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try not mixing HTML and JavaScript:

```
<a id="someLink" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById('someLink').href = 
    (url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1)? 'placeone.htm' : 'placetwo.htm'
</script>
```

or more verbosely:

```
<script>
  var linkElem = document.getElementById('someLink');
  if(url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1) {
    linkElem.href = 'placeone.htm';
  } else {
    linkElem.href = 'placetwo.htm';
  }
</script>
```

Preferably the script should go to a separate file. The way you suggest feels like PHP or JSP but JavaScript does not work this way. In the example above you first render *empty* link and change the `href` attribute afterwards.

Comment: Wouldn't the first part not work because it doesn't have herf="" in the <a> tag?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
<script>
   if (url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1) 
   {
      document.write('<a href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>');
   } else {
      document.write('<a href="placetwo.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to show us where/when this code is executing in your page.  You can't just drop HTML into the middle of a piece of javascript like you were doing.

You can call:

```
document.write('<a href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>');
```

to insert HTML into the current place in the document if this is an inline script.

If this code is not executing inline in the document, then you should not use `document.write()` as that will clear your document and start a new one.  Instead, you would use DOM manipulation functions to insert this into the appropriate place in the page or to change the href on an existing link.  For example to change the href on an existing link when you have this HTML:

```
<a id="myLink" href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>
```

You would use this javascript that must run after the page has been loaded:

```
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");
(url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1) {
    link.href = "placeone.com";
} else {
    link.href = "placetwo.com";
}
```

Comment: Its pretty much the middle of its own code that I am using as a footer to another.

Comment: If the script is inline in the middle of the HTML of the document where you want the HTML inserted, then you can use the first technique with `document.write()`.

Comment: Like this? 

 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (url.indexOf("example.com/") != -1)
{
        document.write('<a href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>');
    } else {
        document.write('<a href="placeone.com" target="_blank">Blahblah</a>');
        }
 </script>

Comment: It's hard to see code in a comment, but that looks like the general idea if the script is an inline script in the middle of your document.

Comment: Still cant get it to work. It shows the link as plain text so I cant click it and go somewhere.

Comment: You will have to show us the overall context in the web page for us to know why it doesn't work.  Remember, you can use the `Edit` link in your original post to add info/code to the post much more easily than you can add it to comments.  Just add a comment after you've edited your question so that people will be notified of the change.